# creating a URL rewrite in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a custom URL rewrite in wordpress.  Basically, I want users to be able set their browser to mysite.com/.well-known/stellar.toml and get the contents of the following file I uploaded as a media file: mysite.com/content/uploads/2016/11/stellar.toml.

I tried the following rewrite rule in functions.php, then saved the permalinks to flush the rewrite rules, but it still didn't work.  Anyone see what I may have done incorrectly?

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  // add rewrite rule
  add_rewrite_rule('.well-known/stellar.toml','wp-content/uploads/2016/11/stellar.toml','top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');
```

Comment: Is this an *example* of what you want to be able to do, or is it truly the only instance? Because this is not maintainable if you want to do it multiple times.  Additionally, this feels off - why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to do this in a single instance.  The reason I want to do it is that my site is joining a network of sites that assume and look for this file is in that specific URI.

Comment: So **the simplest way** to do this is to actually *create that path* on your server, and put the file there, rather than try and fight with a rewrite.  When you visit a WordPress path, if the file exists, it loads that file.